# Using Python and the Pillow Library and CGI for file upload

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've been having hard time importing Image, and CGI together. So, basically I want to upload a gif image, and then display the output which is a thumbnail of the image. I'm getting bunch of errors. I'm unable to use from PIL import Pillow and cgi at the same time. Here is the code below. Your help is highly appreciated. I did hours and hours of research and can't figure that out. I'm getting this error: End of script output before headers: save_file.py

```
#!C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
from PIL import Image
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() #cgitb enabled for bug tracking purposes
try: # Windows needs stdio set for binary mode. 
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
fileitem = form['file']


# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:

   # strip leading path from file name to avoid directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   ext = fn[-3:]
   condi = 'gif'
   if ext == condi:
    open('tmpmedia/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
    selectfunction = "Please select a function from below"
   else:
    message = 'You can only upload a gif image. No file was uploaded'
size = (128,128)
saved = "thumb.jpg"
infile = ('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aztec\\tmpmedia\\gif' + fn)
try:
    im = Image.open(infile)
except:
    print("Unable to load image")
im.thumbnail(size)
im.save(saved)
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print ("<html>")
print("<body>")
print(message)
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you are getting.

Comment: I'm getting this error: End of script output before headers: save_file.py

Comment: I'd suggest putting the print ("Content-Type: text/html\n") at the very top; not sure what you're hosting with, but apache at least is pretty picky about seeing that first.  (Also, do you get see anything in whatever the equivalent of /var/log/httpd/error.log is on Windows).  Lastly... does just the last 6 lines with message set to hello world (to rule this being something other than a pillow issue)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There must be a try statement at the end after the print html, and then I would use from PIL import Image